# how to make JSON string from Normal String?

Tags: android

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++){

            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String myString = contactList.get(i);
            Log.e("Contact List",contactList.get(i));
            String[] myarray = myString.split(",");
            obj.put("is_private","0");
            obj.put("expire_date","0000-00-00");
            obj.put("name",myarray[0]);
            obj.put("phone_no",myarray[1]);
            obj.put("user_id", 1);

            array.put(obj);
        }
```

how we can convert json string to normal string ? please give me answer.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by json string? And what issue(s) do you have with your code?

Comment: you want to get string of JSONArray or JSONObject ?

Answer (score 0):

You can used toString function for this.

```
array.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourstring);
String x = obj.getString("x");

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, may help you.

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    //put your values
    json.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

clear your question please
JsonObject to String use:

```
json.toString();
```

String to JsonObject:

```
String data= "Json format data";
JsonObject obj=new JsonObject(data);
```